# 突然アプリがバックグラウンドへ行く事象が発生し、困っています。

Tags: android

皆様

いつもお世話になっています。

以下に事象が起きており、困っています。
何かご存じの方いたら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか？

1. アプリを起動
2. アプリ内で数ステップ画面を操作
3. アプリ画面内の何かをタップする　（タップイベント等を配置していないViewでも起きる）
4. アプリがバックグラウンドへいってしまい、ホーム画面が表示される

Android6で頻発しています。
Android7では起きないようです。

アプリ構成など必要な情報ありましたら、ご質問ください。

※詳細な手順がありましたので、下記に追記します。

1. アプリを起動。 （Activity Aを起動）
2. Activity Bを起動し、Activity Aはスプラッシュ画像表示用のためすぐにfinish
3. Activity B から Activity C を起動する。 （BはFinishしない。）
4. Activity C から Activity B を起動する。   (CはFinishしない。）
5. Activity B 内の画面内をタップすると、アプリがバックグラウンドへ行ってしまう

※Activityの呼び出しは全て、FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT を指定

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: アプリがクラッシュしているのではなくてバックグラウンドに行っているのでしょうか？ログはトレースしていますか？

Comment: レスありがとうございます！！はい、バックグラウンドへ行っています。ログは見ていますが、アプリ側のイベントは何も発生せずにいきなりバックグラウンドへ遷移しています。OS側も特に出ていません。

Comment: 本情報だけではなかなか回答が難しいかと思います。バックグラウンドにまわる、というのはログ上pauseがかかっているということでよろしいでしょうか？仮にバックグラウンドに回ったアプリが何もしていないならば、フォアグラウンドに回ったアプリが何かしているのだと思いますのでそちらの情報もお願い致します。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。詳細な手順を追記しました。Activityのログ上はdispatchTouchEvent→onPause→onStopと処理は流れています。

Comment: multipost https://teratail.com/questions/63339

Comment: ありがとうございます。
以下を参考に、自己解決しました。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316451/flag-activity-reorder-to-front-in-new-flavors-of-android-os4-4-later

Answer (score 1):

お騒がせしました。自己解決しました。
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT指定の影響のようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316451/flag-activity-reorder-to-front-in-new-flavors-of-android-os4-4-later

Comment: 質問者と同一人物でしょうか？もし、そうであれば[アカウントのマージ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を行えば1つに統合することができます。